# SQL Server Trigger After Insert returns all rows rather than on Inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a form message that is received in an xml statement that populates a table.

I wrote a trigger to message internal personnel, via db-mail, a form message coming in.

The trigger works but the EXE of the trigger returns all records, not just the Inserted Record

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ServRequestEmail 
   ON  schema.dbo.form91415ib 
   for INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
        DECLARE @SUBJECT NVARCHAR(40) = N'';

        SELECT @SUBJECT += CHAR(5) + 'MAINTENANCE REQUEST FROM TRUCK ' + vehicle_number FROM INSERTED;
        SELECT @BODY += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + Left(driver_id, 15) + 'IN TRUCK' + vehicle_number + ' AT '+ created_datetime
        + ' REQUESTED SERVICE ON THE ' + Left(service_on, 7) + 'FOR A SERVICE TYPE OF ' + Left(service_type, 20) + 'AT THE LOCATION OF ' 
        + Left(inroute_city, 30) + 'BECAUSE A SERVICE OF ' + pm_type_due + 'IS DUE.  THE DRIVER ADDED THESE REMARKS:  ' + remarks 
        + ' The driver was located '+ Left(auto_location, 40) + ' when they sent the message in' FROM INSERTED;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED WHERE vehicle_number IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @TO = 'sendto@ouremail.COM',
            @PROFILE_NAME = 'MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATIONS',
            @SUBJECT = @SUBJECT,
            @BODY = @BODY;
        END


END
GO
```

Why would I get a return of all records in the table schema.dbo.form91415ib and not just the Inserted record?

Comment: It send thousands of email or an email with thousands of trucks?

Comment: It sends 1 email with a properly concatenated record for each row in the table, rather than one record in the message body pertaining to only the inserted row